# How to setup a desktop to run 3 independent monitors?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, video, display-resolution

I am trying to build a new desktop and i need to be able to have 3 monitors connected to the desktop.

I am planning to use them as individual monitors (ex. on the 1st monitor i have my local news channel playing, on the 2nd monitor i have youtube open, and on the 3rd monitor i'm working on a spreadsheet).

I will be using Ubuntu 18.04 or later.

How do i build a system like this? My understanding is that i need to install 2 video cards, is that correct?

Will i need to to do a lot of configuration? [I am not a coder]

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know. I have edited the post. thanks

Comment: See https://blog.startech.com/post/connecting-multiple-monitors-multi-stream-transport-and-what-it-means-for-you/ before you head over to https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com where this question is On Topic and welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu natively supports multiple monitors via the settings without any special config (although I can't say 100% it will work with whatever graphics card or cards you are going to use).

I have run various Ubuntu versions on various hardware running multi monitors without any issues. And I have never had to use proprietary drivers, I always use the default drivers. For example my laptop has both a HDMI out and DisplayPort out. So I can use the laptop screen and two monitors and drag windows between the 3 screens as you would expect.

Comment: Another thing to consider - one or more wide/ultrawide monitors. Ubuntu supports window-snapping so you can easily snap one window to the left side of a monitor and another to the right. With an ultrawide monitor you get a lot of screenspace for those two windows. 2 ultrawide monitors can in effect equal 4 usable screens.

Comment: Would you say i need two graphic cards? The one i have now has 1-HDMI, 1-DVI, 1-Display port but it only allows 2 monitors at the same time.

Comment: If you want 3 actual monitors then yes. Or use your current card with 2 normal and/or ultrawide monitors.